# TypeError: Cannot read property 'physics' of undefined

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am making a game in Javascript and I keep on getting this error: Enemy
can be created ‣

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'physics' of undefined
    at new Enemy (src/prefabs/Enemy.js:7:14)
    at r.<anonymous> (test/test_Enemy.js:25:22)
    at c
```

I am not sure what is exactly wrong with the physics property. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code for my enemy class-

```
export default class Enemy extends Phaser.Sprite {

    constructor(game, x, y, bulletLayer, frame) {
        super(game, x, y, 'enemy', frame);

        // initialize your prefab here
        game.physics.enable(this, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

        this.body.velocity.x = -175;
        this.bounceTick = Math.random() * 2;

        this.bulletLayer = bulletLayer;

        this.outOfBoundsKill = true;


        this.willFire = Phaser.Utils.chanceRoll(50);

        console.log(this.willFire);

        if (this.willFire) {
            this.fireTimer = this.game.time.create(false);
            this.fireTimer.add(3500, this.fireShot, this);
            this.fireTimer.start();
        }
    }

    fireShot() {
        let bullet = this.bulletLayer.create(this.x, this.y, "enemyBullet");
        this.game.physics.enable(bullet, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
        bullet.outOfBoundsKill = true;
        bullet.checkWorldBounds = true;
        bullet.body.velocity.x = -250;
    }

    update() {
        this.bounceTick += .02;
        this.y += Math.sin(this.bounceTick) * 1;
    } 
}
```

Here is the code in my test enemy class-

```
describe("Enemy", function () {

        let assert = chai.assert;

let enemy;


//Test fixture, create the same kind of enemy before each test

beforeEach(function() {

    // Stubbing out the features not used in constructor

    let game = sinon.stub();

    game.physics = sinon.stub();

    game.physics.enable = sinon.stub();

    let bullets = sinon.stub();

let screen = sinon.screen();


    enemy = new Enemy(game, 0, 0, bullets,screen);

}); 
it("can be created", function () {

        let enemy = new Enemy();

        assert.isOk(true);

});
```

Answer (score 4):

You create an Enemy here:

`let enemy = new Enemy();`

But as you can see in Enemy's constructor:

`constructor(game, x, y, bulletLayer, frame) {`

It asks for a `game` argument, but you don't provide one. So `game` is undefined, so `game.physics` throws an error.